# filter journalctl output, preserve color

Tags: grep, systemd-journald

I am using journalctl to watch the system by `journalctl -f -p 4`, but I'd like to grep-out some information.

This works: `journalctl -f -p 4|grep -v "maximal mount"`, but grep discards any color info, a small benefit by jornalctl that I'd like to keep. Note that this happens even if I add `--color=never` to grep.

Comment: ... also: same behavior with `--no-pager` added to journalctl

Comment: well, `script -fq /dev/null -c 'journalctl -f -p 4' | grep -v "stuff"` nailed it then... if you write it as anwer I can accept it, thank you!